# where does datetime get its data from asp.net / c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, datetime

I was wondering, where does

```
DateTime.Now;
```

get its data from?

does it get the data from my desktop? actually it does when i'm observing under debugging. I changed my desktop time back an hour, and the datetime.now gave me the exact same date/time.

My real question is, will this still apply when the project is deployed? Will my site continue to fetch time from the users pcs?

The reason for this question is, because i will be using session variables, which i want to dispose after x minutes. And if datetime.now gets the time from the users computer, then it would be a kind of a security issue.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: where ever you deploy the application you will get date and time of that location.

Comment: "Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on this computer, expressed as the local time." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx

Comment: so, basically, it will get the datetime from the server i will deploy the project to ?

Comment: @Mana Exactly. It fetches the current LOCAL time (as per timezone configuration) on the machine the code (i.e. the C# code) is running on. As per documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASP.NET runs at the server. It is getting the time *at the server*. Note that during development, the server often *happens to be* the "user's PC", but that is coincidence.

Comment: Actually, time is the same everywhere and for everyone (when using UTC) ;p

Comment: @leppie: Not `DateTime.Now`, which is local time. `DateTime.UtcNow` would be, assuming all clocks were synchronized...

Answer (score 3):

Your analysis is both right and wrong. DateTime.Now would get the time from the machine where the code is running on. I assume that you have that piece on ASP scripts, that would be running on the web server when you deploy them. So the time would be of the web server rather than user's PC.

You could get the time from User PCs through client side scripts; like JS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep your server Date correctly. As your code will run on server you will keep on getting the correct time. Changing the client machine date won't affect the server time. All your code behind (server side code) will get the correct time.

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net or c# DateTime.Now shows time of server where the application is running.